# Sorting object in javascript (by number)

Tags: javascript, html

Ineed help with correct sorting in created object.

Object (in `for` loop):

```
var labelD = $("#crpc-page label[for='crpc-" + i + "-date']").text();
var valueD = $("#crpc-" + i + "-date").val();
var labelV = $("#crpc-page label[for='crpc-" + i + "-value']").text();
var valueV = $("#crpc-" + i + "-value").val();

console.log("i:" + labelD + " => " + valueD);
console.log("i:" + labelV + " => " + valueV);

dni = Date.parse(valueD);

var sortowanie = {};
var nr = "numer";
var dataD = "dataD";
var wartosc = "wartosc";
sortowanie[nr] = dni;
sortowanie[dataD] = valueD;
sortowanie[wartosc] = valueV;
all_dates.push(sortowanie);
```

Sorting function

```
function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.numer < b.numer) return -1;
    if (a.numer > b.numer) return 1;
    return 0;
}

all_dates.sort(compare);
```

Second alternative sorting function:

```
function sortElement() {
   all_dates.sort(function(a, b){
       return a.numer-a.numer;
   });
}  
sortElement();
```

And now. My problem is that this function sorts only `numer` value not all objects inside `{ ... }` .

Example
console returns:

```
[
  {"numer":1428530400000,"dataD":"04/09/2015","wartosc":"3"},
  {"numer":1441058400000,"dataD":"09/01/2015","wartosc":"1"},
  {"numer":1441576800000,"dataD":"09/07/2015","wartosc":"2"}
]
```

I wish to recive:

```
[
  {"numer":1441058400000,"dataD":"09/01/2015","wartosc":"1"},
  {"numer":1441576800000,"dataD":"09/07/2015","wartosc":"2"},
  {"numer":1428530400000,"dataD":"04/09/2015","wartosc":"3"}
]
```

My brain burns, and I dont know how to switch all elements inside `{}`

Thanks,
Fantazy

Comment: try to replace: `return a.numer-a.numer;`

Answer (score 0):

```
all_dates.sort(function(a,b){
      return b.numer-a.numer;
});
```

It is working according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Your date parse does not work because it is not a US date.

Instead use

```
var parts = valueD.split("/");
dni = new Date(parts[2],parts[1]-1,parts[0]).getTime();
```

**DEMO:**

```js
function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.numer < b.numer) return -1;
    if (a.numer > b.numer) return 1;
    return 0;
}

function getEURTime(str) {
  var parts = str.split("/");
  return new Date(parts[2],parts[1]-1,parts[0]).getTime();
}
var EUR = [
  {"dataD":"04/09/2015","wartosc":"3"},
  {"dataD":"09/01/2015","wartosc":"1"},
  {"dataD":"09/07/2015","wartosc":"2"}
]

for (var i=0;i<EUR.length;i++) {
   EUR[i].numer=getEURTime(EUR[i].dataD);
}
console.log(EUR.sort(compare))
```